# Solution for probelm with openMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I need to turn this into a parallel program for my school. I have been trying on my own for a long time, but have not made any progress. I turned to stuck overflow cause I have heard it is a good place for getting help with coding problems. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char fn[FILENAME_MAX];
    FILE *fin, *fout;
    double (*pos)[3], (*forces)[3];
    double rij[3], d, d2, d3, ene, cut2 = 1000.0;
    unsigned i, j, k, nbodies;

    fin = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fin == NULL) {
        perror(fn);
        exit(-1);
    }
    fscanf(fin, "%ld", &nbodies);
    printf("Reading %d bodies\n", nbodies);

    pos = calloc(nbodies, sizeof(*pos));
    forces = calloc(nbodies, sizeof(*forces));
    if (pos == NULL || forces == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory!\n");
        exit(-2);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nbodies; ++i)
        fscanf(fin, "%lf%lf%lf", pos[i] + 0, pos[i] + 1, pos[i] + 2);

    fclose(fin);
    printf("Calculating......\n");
    clock_t begin = clock();

    ene = 0.0;

    for (i = 0; i < nbodies; ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < nbodies; ++j) {
            d2 = 0.0;
            for (k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
                rij[k] = pos[i][k] - pos[j][k];
                d2 += rij[k] * rij[k];
            }
            if (d2 <= cut2) {
                d = sqrt(d2);
                d3 = d * d2;
                for (k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
                    double f = -rij[k] / d3;

                    forces[i][k] += f;
                    forces[j][k] -= f;
                }
                ene += -1.0 / d;
            }
        }
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double) (end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Calculation time %lf sec\n", time_spent);

    printf("Saving result......");
    // saving results to file
    fout = fopen("results", "w");
    if (fout == NULL) {
        perror("results");
        exit(-1);
    }

    fprintf(fout, "%20.10lE\n", ene);
    for (i = 0; i < nbodies; ++i) {
        fprintf(fout, "%5d ", i);
        for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            fprintf(fout, "%20.10lE", forces[i][j]);
        fprintf(fout, "\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I need this for my school and I could really need some extra help.

Comment: take a look here https://www.cs.usask.ca/~spiteri/CMPT851/notes/nBody.pdf

Answer (score 1):

```c
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) default(none) \
    private(j, k, rij, d, d2, d3) shared(forces, pos, cut2) \
    reduction(+: ene)
for (i = 0; i < nbodies; ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < nbodies; ++j) {
            d2 = 0.0;
            for (k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
                rij[k] = pos[i][k] - pos[j][k];
                d2 += rij[k] * rij[k];
            }
            if (d2 <= cut2) {
                d = sqrt(d2);
                d3 = d * d2;
                for (k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
                    double f = -rij[k] / d3;

                    #pragma omp atomic update
                    forces[i][k] += f;
                    #pragma omp atomic update
                    forces[j][k] -= f;
                }
                ene += -1.0 / d;
            }
        }
    }
```

This should do the trick. If you would parallelize naively, you would get race conditions on `ene`, `rij` and `forces`. As `rij` i just a temporary helper from my understanding, I just made it thread private. `ene` is a result, but just one number, so the `reduction` clause is the way to go. `forces` is a bit big for using a reduction and collisions shouldn't happen all the time, so atomics are the fitting solution. I added `default(none)` such that one has to specify `shared`/`private`/`reduction`/etc for every variable explicitly. This makes it easier to see what you are doing.

Also I used `dynamic` scheduling as different `i` iterations will have a different amount of work due to the limits of the `j` loop. With `static` scheduling (which is the default in most implementations), this would make for bad load-balancing and therefore decrease performance. You could try specifying different chunk sizes for the scheduling to optimize this. `guided` scheduling might also be worth a try.

An algorithmic alternative would be to go aver all particles in the `j` loop. This would mean that more work is done, but you would need less synchronization (in this case atomics) and it might be faster because of that.

```c
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) \
    private(j, k, rij, d, d2, d3) shared(forces, pos, cut2) \
    reduction(+: ene)
for (i = 0; i < nbodies; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < nbodies; ++j) {
            if (i == j) {
                continue;
            }
            d2 = 0.0;
            for (k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
                rij[k] = pos[i][k] - pos[j][k];
                d2 += rij[k] * rij[k];
            }
            if (d2 <= cut2) {
                d = sqrt(d2);
                d3 = d * d2;
                for (k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
                    double f = -rij[k] / d3;

                    forces[i][k] += f;
                }
                ene += -0.5 / d;
            }
        }
    }
```